# Play2.2 Why Assets.at does not compile without specifying path parameter name?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I have something in Play 2.2 which I cannot explain.
So the following line from my "routes" file compiles fine:
`GET      /css/*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/stylesheets", file)`

But when I remove "path=" part from there
`GET      /css/*file      controllers.Assets.at("/public/stylesheets", file)`

i see following error in the console:

> `)' expected but`"' found In C:\Workspace\Private\Play\bubusik\conf\routes at line 9.

So I am wondering is it required to explicitly provide the name of the parameter to the at() function? Is it some undocumented requirement for the Play template engine?

Answer (score 1):

Well it has got to do with regular expression routes uses. In short if you are using an identifier then you can use it. But if you enter a value, then you need to specify the function argument name for the value. To explain it, look at below scenario:

```
POST     /:id                   controllers.Application.index(id)
```

With `index2(id)`, the regex extracts `id` from url specified and then uses it. But if you with to pass some default value as in your case then the convention is to specify the argument name.

```
POST     /:id                   controllers.Application.index2(id,name="defaultName")
```

Like above, if `defaultName` has to be be passes as default argument then you need to specify the argument name of `index2` function (`name` in this case).

This convention is used to distinguish identifiers (ex `id` in first case) with values you specify. If `"defaultName"` is used instead of `name="defaultName"` then it will not work in case on `Int`.

Comment: Hi Jatin, thank you for your comment. But I am not trying to pass any default value, I am just passing a regular String value to the String-typed function parameter. Default values can only be defined in the function declaration while my case involves a function call.

Comment: Hello. I am sorry, by default I mean a fixed value for all requests. Like in your case `"/public/stylesheets"` is passed for all requests

Comment: Jatin, is this convention mentioned somewhere in the Play docs?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar I am not sure if it is mentioned any where but it is how I have been using it. This link (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaRouting) tells to use `path= ` though. Couldnt find explicit link